# FontFamily handle reference to font file

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Button` control and I want to apply a font from a custom folder to it.
In order to do so, I create a `System.Windows.Media.FontFamily` object using `new FontFamily(new Uri(mypath), myfamily)`, and it's working fine. But at some moment I want to remove my path (with font files), and I get access denied error.

I tried to recreate the `FontFamily` object with empty constructor, but the error is still there. This issue smells like .NET bug.

How I can unload FontFamily or delete reference from font file?

Example:

```
void setFont()
{
    button.FontFamily = new FontFamily(new Uri("file:///d:/MyFonts/"), "./#Pericles Light");
}

void unsetFont()
{
    button.FontFamily = new FontFamily();
}
```

After calling the `unsetFont()` method, MyFonts folder is still denied.

Comment: *This issue smells like .NET bug*... you shouldn't be so quick to point the finger as it is most probable that the bug is actually coming from *your* code. Of course, none of us can confirm that though, because you haven't bothered to [provide a code example that clearly demonstrates your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's not a bug, it is more of a design philosophy behind WPF.  Much influenced by a "step-aside, let us smart guys take care of this" attitude.  There is no way you can explicitly say "I'm not using this font anymore", neither FontFamily nor Typeface have a Dispose() method.  Fonts are also heavily cached, they are very expensive to create, you can't get to the cache at all.  A hail-Mary call to GC.Collect() is pretty unlikely to solve the issue, you'll have to deal with the way it works.  Which does mean you either have to copy the font yourself or give up on the need to delete the directory.